# How to "Leave a trace when moving over a map in a website"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

look at this gif first. before reading

http://cl.ly/image/0v0F3n0d1w0k

[image: Map Trail]

---

my website has a map background and is divided in sections.

when you scroll you go to the next section and the map behind changes depending on the type of section ( for example america section will show america. I already achieved that by using background-position and changing the X and Y coordinates of background )

now i want to achieve this effect : 
i added a pin and it stays at the center of the screen. 
so when you change section it is always in the center ( it doesn't move )

but i want to draw a line from the starting center X Y to the destination X Y ( that will be the next center )  like in the video  in the link above

any idea about which technology i could use ? ( i would search for some tutorial and learn it )

maybe using SVG?

idea 1 ) SVG

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html
Path commands
L   x,y lineto  Draws a line from current pen location to specified point x,y

Comment: External link content should also be *directly* included in the question, otherwise if the link expires or is no longer available the question because useless for future readers.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I don't think this user has sufficient permission to include an image in the post.

Comment: i do know but i dont have 10 reputation yet so i can't post images inside questions

Comment: Animated gifs are not supported, I think. I tried editing your post to include the image and I got 'format not supported' error.

Comment: I upvoted the question (its a good but incomplete question), but you should always include what you attempted to do to complete your question.  Otherwise it appears you are asking us to write code for you.

Comment: well yeah, actually i just needed an hint on which technologies can achieve this effect. then i'll search for some tutorial and learn that ( SVG seems like the solution for now )

Comment: The problem with that type of question is that; Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  This could be completed via Google Maps, Bing Maps, Mapquest Maps, Esri, SVG, jQuery/Html5 Canvas...

Comment: it really depends on your definition of "map" in this case. If you are using a map library such as leaflet.js then it comes with functions such as pan/zoom/centre. You may need to extend the library yourself for the lines to happen.   But if the map you're talking about is simply an image, then i suppose js+svg is what you need